# SQL Historical Changes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been trying to wrap my head around this for some time now and just can't seem to find a good solution so I am consulting the overflow. I have a table which looks a little like this:

```
[EmployeeId]  [int] IDENTITY(1,1)  NOT NULL,
[Name]  [varchar](255)  NOT NULL,
[Title]  [varchar](255)  NULL,
[QueueId]  [int]  NOT NULL,
[SupervisorId]  [int]  NULL,
```

Employees are moved from one queue to another queue at different time intervals. how should I structure my second table so I can see not only how many people where in a queue at a specific time interval but also who they were?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say the table will look like this:

```
[EmployeeId]  [int] IDENTITY(1,1)  NOT NULL,
[QueueId]  [int]  NOT NULL,
[Start] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[End] [datetime] NOT NULL
```

The unfortunate thing is you have to go back and "end date" the prior row. If I am the one doing it, I will skip the [End] and create a view on top of the table that will supply the [End].

The view will look like

```
SELECT A.[EmployeeId]
     , A.[QueueId]
     , A.[Start]
     , COALESCE(MIN([B.Start]),'9999-12-31') as [END]
  FROM Table A
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Table B
    ON A.[EmployeeId] = B.[EmployeeId]
   AND A.[Start] < B.[Start]
```

If you do it this way, you cannot use BETWEEN when joining to this view. You have to say >= [Start] and < [END]. Anyway, it's safer and more robust since you don't have to decide on a date/time "rounding" unit.

Comment: Robert, that is a great idea. How would you do the View though. I thought the same thing last night but with End date being left NULL.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I really was lost for a while because I needed to make sure I could track not only where agents are currently queued but where they were for different intervals and this will allow me to do just that. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
queueid int
status varchar(20)
start datetime
end datetime
```

Comment: Isn't this missing the "who they were" bit?

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd table should have a primary key, datetime, and count columns. However,  you will need a 3rd table that lists the people in the queue, since the count & list reside in different hierarchical levels.